# Only the first row row is required field - Dynamic table Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic, knockout.js

```
<table style="margin-left:20px" border="0" class="ledgergrid" width="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                            <th>A. Citation</th>
                                            <th>B. Relevant Finding(s)</th>
                                            <th>C. Overlap of Populations and/or Settings</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: listCitations"> 
                                        <tr style="background-color:#eeeeee;" >  
                                            <td width="1%">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn-xs" id="delete" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCitation.bind($data), attr: { title: $parent.deleteCitationToolTip }, visible: $parent.lastIndexCitations() > 2"> X </button>
                                                <td width="33%" ><textarea name="citation" class="" style="width:80% !important; height:60px;" data-bind="css: $parent.KCitationCSS, attr: {id: 'citation' + ($index() + 1), title: $parent.citationToolTip}, value: $data.KCitation"></textarea></td>
                                                <td width="33%"><textarea name="relevantFindings" class="" style="width:80% !important; height:60px;" data-bind=" css: $parent.relevantFindingsCSS, attr: {id: 'relevantFindings' + ($index() + 1), title: $parent.relevantFindingsToolTip}, value: $data.KRelevantFindings"></textarea></td>
                                                <td width="33%"><textarea name="overlapofPopulations" class="" style="width:80% !important; height:60px;" data-bind=" css: $parent.overlapofPopulationsCSS, attr: {id: 'overlapofPopulations' + ($index() + 1), title: $parent.overlapofPopulationsToolTip}, value: $data.KOverlapofPopulations"></textarea></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                      </table>
```

I have displayed 4 rows in default case, but all of them showed as required. I would like to have only the first row required, and the rest are not required. FYI all the table is dynamic! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to say first column after the button? From the code shared, I can see only 1 row. Am assuming that its 1st column (A. Citation) thats required and needs special look & feel. If yes, here is CSS code:

```
.ledgergrid td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Well,I have a dynamic table. I could control and let 4 of them displayed, but that is not the problem. The problem I would like only the first row CSS”required” and the rest wouldn’t be. Thank you!